# Fancier "Quote" formatting.

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Considering that English.SE is about language, I think there should be a fancier quote formatting for short quotes. (Like a huge quote mark in the background. - This will emphasize the concept of quote.)

Comment: We've had fancy quote formatting since the day the new design was launched, over three weeks ago.

Comment: @Martha: This question only got pushed to the top because I tagged it "status-completed", and so it appeared to some to be a new question.  At the time it was asked, the question was relevant.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: whoops! For some reason, my brain parsed the Nov. 11 date as Dec. 11. //blush

Comment: @Martha: it's still not as fancy as on tex.SE :-(

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a good idea. It should be fairly simple to implement, and could help users.

Edit:

> As per Mitch's comment below, fancy quote thingy here.

Comment: To see the fancy quote formatting, start a line with ">" in a question or answer. This is explained under blockquotes on the [markdown editing help](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/editing-help) page.