# “Style” and “formatting” tags on Meta: synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, retag-request, meta

In the real world, there are any number of ways to distinguish *style* from *formatting*, but on Meta.EL&U, neither has been specified in the tag wikis. They are both a jumble of questions about which type of formatting to use to represent different elements in a post, about how to indicate such formatting in Markdown, about SE changing the visual presentation of those elements, and about tone and writing style.

Tagged with [formatting](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formatting):

1. [About formatting ellipses](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4200/about-formatting-ellipses)
2. [Should we fix backticks?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3358)
3. [What's the best way to format quotes within quotes?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1180/whats-the-best-way-to-format-quotes-within-quotes)

Tagged with [style](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style):

4. [What emphasis to use when referring to words?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363)
5. [Inline quotes formatting](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3849/inline-quotes-formatting)
6. [Should we have a standard way of indicating deliberately malformed sentences?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26/should-we-have-a-standard-way-of-indicating-deliberately-malformed-sentences)

Tagged with neither:

7. [Formatting a Quote](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4128/formatting-a-quote)
8. [Fancier "Quote" formatting.](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393/fancier-quote-formatting)
9. [Is Underlining Available as a Markup Format](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5264/is-underlining-available-as-a-markup-format)

Neither [formatting](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formatting) nor [style](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style) is heavily used, each with 15–16 posts. Therefore, I propose **merging them as [style](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style)** with [formatting](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formatting) as a synonym, followed by cleanup relegating a few questions to [design](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) and others.

Alternatively, a case can certainly made for keeping them distinct, but as they are currently used almost interchangeably, I suspect it may not be worth the upkeep on a relatively small number of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, [style](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style) is a synonym for [writing-style](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-style), which is the master.

Meanwhile, [formatting](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formatting) is gone,  although [format](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/format) exists and matches 13 questions, mostly closed.  One could make [formatting](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formatting) the master and [format](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/format) the synonym, but I don’t find the tag particularly clear as things stand.

This is because that [searching for questions that happen to contain *format* (or *formatting*, etc.)](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=is%3aquestion%20format) yields around 400 results that are all over the place, with some being about orthography, some about typography/typesetting, others about citation formats, and still others about general layout design questions.

I agree it doesn’t seem very well understood and agreed upon, and there is no tag wiki excerpt guidance for it.

I don’t reckon it would be the best idea to merge the existing [format](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/format) questions with [writing-style](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-style) any longer, but this is just a hunch. If you could please look them over and perhaps update your request for the current scenario, perhaps we can get these taken care of, one way or the other.